# Can you include totals and detail rows in a single mySQL query?

Tags: mysql

None of the questions on file seems to be about my precise problem.

Is it possible to sequence detail lines based on the number of detail lines for that order you have in a single query?

Consider the following simplified table:

```
Order number Article number
------------ --------------
123           1
123           2
123           3
234           1
234           2
345           1
456           1
456           2
456           3
456           4
456           5
```

The number of detail lines for each order would be

```
Order number Number of lines
------------ ---------------
123           3
234           2
345           1
456           5
```

Is it possible to select the order number, article number in descending order by total number of detail lines for each detail line?  In other words the desired results are

```
Order number Article number
------------ --------------
456          1
456          2
456          3
456          4
456          5
123          1
123          2
123          3
234          1
234          2
345          1
```

I can do it with multiple queries and temporary tables or extra columns.  Neither simple SELECTS, SELF JOINs nor UNIONs appear to give me the results I want.  Is it possible to do with a single query?

Comment: This seems to have been asked before

Comment: And if there is a tie on the article count do you want the article numbers to be inner mixed fro the same order or separated out by order.  if separated is there any order to the ties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should work as it's getting the count from the join and then ordering it by the count.

```
select t1.orderNumber,  t1.articleNumber from myTable t1
inner join
(
  select orderNumber,  count(articleNumber) as count from myTable 
   group by orderNumber

) t2
on t1.orderNumber = t2.orderNumber  
order by t2.count desc, t1.orderNumber, t1.articleNumber
```

To better expain it:

We are first selecting all the data, then we are inner joining a table that has the count for each order number, once we have this we can then order it by count `DESC` so we get the order number with the highest count on top and we can then add additional sorting in the `Order By`

Comment: order by articleNumber reference is ambiguous  You likely want T1.articleNumber.  (you don't need article number in the subquery/derived table/inlineview so why include it?; You could count by it instead of *)  It would also be nice to explain your approach.  since the original question seems to be having trouble with that aspect.  Also if count has ties, you will mix order numbers.  no example in data like this but likely not what OP wants; so you may want to order by orderNumber before articleNumber to handle ties cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @xQbert for the comments, you are right and I made  the adjustments.

Comment: Thank you.  That solves the problem.  I've accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the interests of future readers (when MySQL 8.x is production ready and it supports window functions) you can avoid the intermediate subquery and join by using `COUNT() OVER(partition by ...)` like this:

> ```
> select t1.orderNumber,  t1.articleNumber f
> from myTable t1
> order by
>     count(*) over(partition by t1.orderNumber) DESC
>   , t1.orderNumber
>   , t1.articleNumber
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> orderNumber |  f
> ----------: | -:
>         456 |  1
>         456 |  2
>         456 |  3
>         456 |  4
>         456 |  5
>         123 |  1
>         123 |  2
>         123 |  3
>         234 |  1
>         234 |  2
>         345 |  1
> ```

*ps: The example above done in MariaDB 10.2 to show MySQL(ish) syntax at work* (& it's standards complaint SQL anyway).

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=4c0cb36e6cde9cb7f630109849a0cc77)*

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the problem correctly, following query should work:

```
select t1.order_number, t1.Article_number
from t1
inner join (select order_number,count(*) as cnt from t1 group by order_number) as t2
on t1.order_number = t2.order_number
order by t2.cnt desc,t1.order_number,t1.Article_number;
```

Hope it helps!